# How to get a single response when going through an array using logic

Tags: c#

Testing interview questions:

I have an `if` statement to check if all condition of an IP address are met and if it is I want it to write if the IP address is valid or not. I'm supposed to be using loops logic myself and not use other class libraries such as IPAddress.parse

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string ipAddress = "10.121.300.21";
    string[] sections = ipAddress.Split('.');
    string invalid = "The IP address: {0} is invalid!";
    string valid = "The IP address: {0} is valid";

    for (var i = 0; i < sections.Length; i++)
    {
        double ipNum = int.Parse(sections[i]);

        if (ipNum > 0 && ipNum < 255 && sections.Length == 4)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(valid, ipAddress);
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine(invalid, ipAddress);
            Console.WriteLine("section number {0} is invalid. ", sections[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

Right now it returns:

````
The IP address: 10.121.300.21 is valid
The IP address: 10.121.300.21 is valid
The IP address: 10.121.300.21 is invalid!
section number 300 is invalid. 
The IP address: 10.121.300.21 is valid```
````

I would like it to return whether it's valid or not in one line instead of running through each item in the array individually

Comment: Have you considered https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.ipaddress.tryparse?view=net-5.0#System_Net_IPAddress_TryParse_System_String_System_Net_IPAddress__ or https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.ipaddress.-ctor?view=net-5.0#System_Net_IPAddress__ctor_System_Byte___ instead?

Comment: Do you mean that you want to only output a single console line specifying whether or not the IP is valid?

Comment: Then could use Linq. Something like: var isValid = !sections.Any(x=> <0 || x >255); 
Ps. This is not  valid ip address checker. Use build in NET https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.ipaddress.tryparse?view=net-5.0

Comment: https://dotnetfiddle.net/TWd5uJ might get you started. There are elements I haven't done perfectly (e.g. doesn't handle ipv6, doesn't use ipaddress.tryparse etc), so there is opportunity for you to improve it. Also check out the answers below.

Comment: Please clarify if this interview question requires you to implement this logic yourself using loops, or if more convenient approaches (e.g. LINQ, `IPAddress.*Parse`) can be used.  To me, using something like `IPAddress.TryParse()` defeats the purpose of the exercise, but perhaps this is supposed to be testing one's knowledge of the Base Class Library.

Answer (score 0):

You can potentially do this in one check with [`IPAddress.TryParse`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.ipaddress.tryparse?view=net-5.0)

> Determines whether a string is a valid IP address.

Which will work with both IPv4 and IPv6. However you will need to read the remarks to see if it truly suits your needs

**Remarks**

> Note that this method accepts as valid an ipString value that can be
> parsed as an Int64, and then treats that Int64 as the long value of an
> IP address in network byte order, similar to the way that the
> IPAddress constructor does. This means that this method returns true
> if the Int64 is parsed successfully, even if it represents an address
> that's not a valid IP address. For example, if ipString is "1", this
> method returns true even though "1" (or 0.0.0.1) is not a valid IP
> address and you might expect this method to return false. Fixing this
> bug would break existing apps, so the current behavior will not be
> changed. Your code can avoid this behavior by ensuring that it only
> uses this method to parse IP addresses in dotted-decimal format.

```
var ipAddress = "2001:0db8:85a3:0000:0000:8a2e:0370:7334";
Console.WriteLine($"{ipAddress}: {(IPAddress.TryParse(ipAddress, out _) ? "Valid" : "invalid")}");
```

**Output**

```
2001:0db8:85a3:0000:0000:8a2e:0370:7334: Valid
```

Comment: the purpose of this exercise is to implement logic myself and not use other class libraries

Comment: @AbbeAzale all good, however you only just added that stipulation. Ill leave this here incase any future readers need a reliable way to pass an ipaddress.. good luck :)